# SQL Server query from two databases in asp.net

Tags: sql-server

I have an asp.net application which uses several databases on several servers. Now I need to join two tables from two databases on different servers.

I use two connection strings, what should I write?

```
query = select studentcode,mobile 
        from learning.dbo.students 
        where stcode in (select stcode from hs.dbo.currentetrm)

Dim ds As New DataSet()
ad.Fill(ds)

GridView1.DataSource = ds
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Where `learning` is one database on one server with its own login and `hs` is another database with another login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Use linked server so that you can do everything with single Connection String.
2. Use 2 Connections and bring the data onto the application side (C#). Now that you have both datasets at same place, you can do the required logic applied.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this from within ASP.NET, not with two connection strings.

One way to accomplish this is to setup these databases as [linked servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189580.aspx) - this will allow you to run the query on one of the servers using one login and perform the join there through the linked server.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a single query without linked servers, but you could query them separately and then filter your first table based on values from the second one in your .NET code.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: In short, you can but they have to be linked: See Oded's answer.

<s>In short, you can't.</s>

A SQL query is processed and executed by a single SQL server.  This means that a single query cannot join two tables on two different servers.

Depending on the situation, it is probably a better idea to import a table from one server to the other, and then do the query on that server.  Hence, the question is "Why do you have related data on two separate servers?"

Comment: Not entirely correct - you can use linked servers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189580.aspx